# Why is LINQ ToList not used here?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, enumeration

I see the following code:

```
using(var iterator = source.GetEnumerator()) {...}
```

Where `source` is a `IEnumerable<T>`.

What is the advantage of doing the above versus converting `source` into a `List<T>` and then iterating over it?

Comment: With `ToList` you will iterate the source twice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting it to a list will iterate the enumerable once and copy all the references (or even values for value types) into a new `List<>`. Then, you would iterate over the list. That means you would iterate twice.

Using the `IEnumerable<>` as a source for enumeration iterates over the sequence only once.

Why someone decided to do the iteration manually using the enumerator instead of leaving the details to a `foreach` is unclear from the small scope you posted.

Comment: Why might the author have used `using`.  I thought it was for objects that need to be disposed of automatically.

Comment: @shiva Because the `IEnumerator<T>` that is returned implements `IDisposable`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: So does that mean every time I use `IEnumerator<T> ` I should put into `using`?

Comment: @shiva If you use one directly, then yes. Personally, I have never used one, I could always handle my needs by using a `foreach` to iterate sequences.

Answer (score 2):

1. Converting to a `List<T>` would require additional memory and CPU cycles to perform the conversion not to mention you'd be iterating over the data twice.
2. There's no need to convert to a `List<T>` before iterating. `foreach` can iterate over anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.